# Angular hidden div dynamically unhiding best practices

Tags: html, angular

I'm building an Angular application with a login page. The login page contains the following elements:

- Login form
- Password forgot form
- Password forgot acknowledge message
- Password reset form (you end up here after clicking the link sent by e-mail)
- Loading spinner

At first, the `login form` should be presented. When you click the `forgot my password` link, the login form should disappear and the `password forgot form` should appear in which a user can enter his email address and press a button to request a new password. Next on, the user is presented the `password forgot acknowledge message` with text stating what is going to happen next.

When the user clicks the link sent by e-mail he is redirected to the login page again and presented with the `password reset form` where he can enter his desired password.

What I have currently done is written all divs successively in the `login.component.html page`. By default all are hidden except for the `login form` using `(example) *ngIf="forgotpassword" [@fadeInOutRight]`. Then, based on buttons or links clicked on the page dynamically divs fly in and out of the screen using Angular Animations.

I was wondering if this is good practice or if there's any other technique that should be used to dynamically change the content of the page.

Any tips are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I usually use separate pages (with separate routing) for each div(screen) - this approach decrease complexity of your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use routing for the purpose you are describing. Have a look at https://angular.io/guide/router

That's at least how I would do it. It has multiple advantages:

- Clearly seperates the code into cohesive components that serve one purpose
- The users and you can now directly access the routes
- You don't have to write the hiding/switching logic, because Angluar already provides that
- The clear seperation makes it easier to test

Comment: Does this also work if only a small part of the content of the page should change? Of course the login page also has styling, which I'd rather not repeat, that would also defeat the purpose of dynamic content

Comment: Yes. Only the content of the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` changes. And you can even declare child routes. The linked angular documentation explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

first ngIf does the trick, you can also consider using the [hidden] property. The difference is with ngIf, you create and delete elements from the DOM, while with the [hidden] property you just hide them. But as long as your users will not spam switching from one form to another, I think it's fine using ngIf.

I would recommand splitting your login page in components. For example, one for the login form itself, another one for the password forgot form, etc...
This way, when the user click the forgot password button, you just direct her/him to the corresponding component.

Hope that helps